# Symfony2: Handle a form in a different action where it was created

Tags: forms, symfony

I created a form with a Select field and I need to process the response in a different action.
The action "showInfo" shows the info of a game and draws a form with a list of the user's available characters for joining the game. The form is processed by the action "joinGame" which recives the slug of the game in the url and the id of the character by the form.
How could I handle the selected option in the other action?

**showInfoAction**

```
/*...*/

$free_charact = $em->getRepository('PlayerBundle:Character')->findBy(
    array(
        'user' => $user,
        'game' => null),
        array()
    );

/*...*/

if ($free_charact) {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($free_charact)
        ->add('charact_join', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $array_select,
            'multiple'  => false,
        ))
        ->getForm();

$array_render['form'] = $form->createView();

return $this->render(
    'GameBundle:Default:game_info.html.twig',
    $array_render
    );
```

**joinGameAction**

```
/*...*/

$req = $this->getRequest();

if ($req->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $postData = $req->request->get('form_charact_join');
    $id_charac = $postData[0];
    $charac_change = $em->getRepository('PlayerBundle:Character')->findOneById($id_charac);

    //Check if the character is property of the user
    $charac_change->setGame($game);
    $em->persist($charac_change);
    $em->flush();

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'You are a player of this game now!');
}

    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('info_game', array('slug' => $slug)));
```

**game_info.html.twig**

```
<form action="{{ path('join_game', {'slug': game.slug}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.charact_join) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Join" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

Oh, I see. This is because of how the form rendering works, specifically with how fields are named.

When a form object does not have a specific type, Symfony will use `form` as the base name of the data.  What that means is that your choice list is rendered like this

```
<select name="form[charact_join]" multiple="multiple">
  <!-- choices --->
</select>
```

So, in order to retrieve it properly, you have to address it as such

```
$postData = $req->request->get('form[charact_join]');
```

But that's not enough! If we look at the [API docs for this get method](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html#method_get), we can see it has a couple more parameters: `$default` and `$deep` - it's the 3rd one that we care about here. You want the getter to parse the deep path reference we've provided

```
$postData = $req->request->get('form[charact_join]', null, true);
```

Of course, none of this is nearly as troublesome when you make your own form types and bind data to them from the request.

### /EDIT

This shouldn't be a problem. You didn't post your template/view, but that's where this would be handled.

**GameBundle:Default:game_info.html.twig**

```
<form action="{{ path('route_name_for_join_game_action') }}" method="post">
  {{ form_errors(form) }}
  {{ form_rest(form) }}
  <input type="submit" value="Join Game" />
</form>
```

Comment: It is. $id_charac is empty. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct way to pick the data from the request. I updated the question with the template.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the previous answer, I solved it simply.
I get **the form data** using its id:

```
$form = $request->get('myproject_mybundle_myformtype', null, true);
```

On the other hand, if you want the **whole form**, use this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType());
```

And use one of that 3 methods, depending your Symfony version:

```
$form->bind($request); //deprecated in Symfony 2.3
$form->submit($request); //deprecated in Symfony 3.0
$form->handleRequest($request); //not deprecated yet
```

With the form you can use methods like:

```
$form->isSubmitted();
$form->isValid();
```

Hope it helps!